# Valgrind for C program reporting unbelievable invalid write

Tags: c, valgrind

Anyone have problems with Valgrind incorrectly reporting an invalid write? I've got a C program with this loop:

```
void myfunc4(int *myData, ...) 
{
 int *variable1, *variable2, ii, ss, bb, jj;
 ...
 bb = 0;
 for (ii=0; ii<ss; ii++) {  
   for (jj=0; jj<(variable2[ii]-variable1[ii]+1); jj++) {
       myData[bb] = variable1[ii] + jj; /* valgrind reports error is on this line */
       bb = bb+1;
   }
   printf("ss = %d, ii = %d, bb = %d \n", ss, ii, bb);
 }
}
```

I run Valgrind using,

```
valgrind --log-file=./logfile --leak-check=full ./myProgram
```

and the first and only "Invalid" error it lists is:

```
==6135== Invalid write of size 4
==6135==    at 0x4090AA: myfunc4 (myfunc4.c:170)
==6135==    by 0x408527: myfunc3 (myfunc3.c:168)
==6135==    by 0x406CA1: myfunc2 (myfunc2.c:84)
==6135==    by 0x410163: myfunc1 (myfunc1.c:133)
==6135==    by 0x413726: main (myProgram.c:511)
==6135==  Address 0x1077c250 is 209,712 bytes inside a block of size 209,715 alloc'd
==6135==    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==6135==    by 0x408248: myfunc3 (myfunc3.c:119)
==6135==    by 0x406CA1: myfunc2 (myfunc2.c:84)
==6135==    by 0x410163: myfunc1 (myfunc1.c:133)
==6135==    by 0x413726: main (myProgram.c:511)
==6135== 
==6135== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==6135== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
```

Valgrind states the error occurs in the line of code:

```
myData[bb] = variable1[ii] + jj;
```

If I step through the program at that point using gdb, it runs fine. The last printf displayed before the loop completes is:

```
ss = 687, ii = 686, bb = 2690
```

I can't seem to observe any problem outside of Valgrind. Valgrind consistently gives this error, but gdb consistently shows no problem.

The memory allocated for `myData` is, as Valgrind correctly reports, 209712 bytes, which is room for 209712/4 = 52428 integers (I'm using Linux 64 bit machine). From the `printf` statement, I can see the for loop exits with bb=2690 as it should. So the largest index used for array `myData[bb]` (where Valgrind complains) is `myData[2689]`.

Can anyone shed some light where I can look next? I've been staring at this all day. I've not used Valgrind much, and I don't want to call it a lier, but am I doing something wrong here? Any advice much appreciated.

UPDATE 1

The call to `myfunc4()` inside `myfunc3()` is:

```
int *myData, lengthA; 
...
myData = malloc( sizeof(int) * lengthA / 10); 
myfunc4(myData);
```

UPDATE 2

If I modify the loop to include an `if (bb>10000)` statement, gdb never tests true, but Valgrind does. The compiled program is the same. Anyone have any insight what's going on?

```
void myfunc4(int *myData, ...) 
{
 int *variable1, *variable2, ii, ss, bb, jj;
 ...
 bb = 0;
 for (ii=0; ii<ss; ii++) {  
   for (jj=0; jj<(variable2[ii]-variable1[ii]+1); jj++) {
       myData[bb] = variable1[ii] + jj; 
       bb = bb+1;
       if (bb>10000) {
          printf("bb=%d \n", bb); /* valgrind executes this line but gdb does not */
          exit(1);
       }
   }
   printf("ss = %d, ii = %d, bb = %d \n", ss, ii, bb);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet which calls the myfunc4?

Comment: I would use int32_t instead of int

Comment: I don't see from Update how `outArray1` is `malloced` before entering `myfunc4`

Comment: I've only shown the code related to the loop in question, so just ignore `outArray1`, `length_outArray1`, `length_myData`, and `NFACTOR`, which are in the call to `myfunc4` but otherwise aren't discussed herein. I can delete them if confusing...  Nevermind -- I deleted them to simplify the discussion. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: 209,715 is an odd number so it is weird to see it in the message

Comment: Good point perreal, that's my bad (in simplifying the code). Currently I show `myData=malloc(sizeof(int)*52428))` but in reality it is `malloc(sizeof(int)*lengthA/10)` where `lengthA` is an integer, so the divide by 10 causes fractional truncation which can give rise to an odd number. The limit shouldn't ever be reached though. I'll update the code...

Comment: Does it have something to do with integer being considered as 4 bytes by valgrind and your code is actually doing a 8 byte (64 bit system) write? Just a guess. Have you printed the sizeof(int) from your code?

Comment: If I print sizeof(int) it reports 4.

Comment: `valgrind` does not lie; it tells you the unpleasant truth, and is utterly invaluable because that is what it does.  You say `bb` in `myfunc4` never reaches more than 2690; `valgrind` is telling you that `myData` is starting at an address such that `myData[2690]` is writing beyond the end of the allocated space.  You need to look at the code in `myfunc3()` to see what is passed to `myfunc4()`; the calculation of the address passed to `myfunc4()` as `myData` is wrong.  Since `myfunc3()` allocates the space, you shouldn't need to look elsewhere for the trouble.

Comment: `Valgrind consistently gives this error, but gdb consistently shows no problem.`. I know that on HP-UX their customized gdb has a special mode to check memory problems and you have to turn it on in order to check allocations errors. However GNU gdb does not have this HP gdb capabilities. So it is of no use to say that gdb `shows no problem`.

Comment: If this code is part of a larger, more complex system, then you might be suffering from a problem that results from code that wasn't uploaded here. Can you recreate it in a "sandbox" process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the bug. Malloc, of course, doesn't initialize to zero, and I had an `if` statement (not shown above) that set some array values, but there wasn't a `else` statement to catch the other path to set the same array values, so that other path used the unitialized values which led to bad behavior.

In this debugging effort, gdb did a better job initializing arrays to zero (via malloc) compared to Valgrind. Not that one should rely on that, but that appears to be the difference between results obtained with gdb and Valgrind here, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual number of bytes allocated for the data and pass it to the function:

```
size_t szData = sizeof(int) * lengthA / 10; 
myData = malloc(szData);
myfunc4(myData, szData);
```

and check the access to verify valgrind:

```
/* .... */
assert((bb +1) * sizeof(int) < szData);
myData[bb] = variable1[ii] + jj;
```